# Pass a string literal from html to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, escaping, literals

In IE9 I am getting an error Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'populatedropdown' is undefined on the line `<input type="button"....`

I assume I am not escaping the literal values correctly.  How should I change?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Add items to dropdown</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
function populatedropdown(var devicelist) {
    var devList = document.frm.optdevices;
    var arrDev = split(devicelist, ";");

     devList.options.length = 0; // this removes existing options

     for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
         var option = new Option(arrDev[i],i);
         devList.options[i] = option; 
     }
}

</script>

</head>
<body>
<form name="frm">

<select name="optdevices">
</select>

<input type="button" value="TestAdd" onclick="populatedropdown('201;202;203;')" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `Unexpected token var` on the first line of script. Also, separate your JavaScript from your HTML (attach event listeners on page load).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should not write var via defining function, and second use of function split is wrong, split should be used like 
`var result = strToSplit.split(";")`, if you wanna split by `;` , you can read about split here [Javascript Split method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

here is working snippet

```
function populatedropdown(devicelist) {
    var devList = document.frm.optdevices;
    var arrDev = devicelist.split(";");

     devList.options.length = 0; // this removes existing options

     for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
         var option = new Option(arrDev[i],i);
         devList.options[i] = option; 
     }
}
```

just tested on IE9

Comment: Ah I assumed it was the html.  Very new to JavaScript.

Comment: @user619818, website - [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com), that I have mentioned, is a pretty good website for newbies, I have begun with it by myself

Answer (score 1):

Separate the JavaScript from HTML and remove syntax error. See this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GvAYY/)

```
function populatedropdown(devicelist) {
    var devList = document.frm.optdevices;
    var arrDev = devicelist.split(';'); // split not defined

     devList.options.length = 0; // this removes existing options

     for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
         var option = new Option(arrDev[i],i);
         devList.options[i] = option; 
     }
}

// on window load
window.addEventListener('load', function load(){
    // attach event listener to button
    document.getElementById('testID').addEventListener('click', function click(){
        populatedropdown('201;202;203;');
    }, false);
}, false);
​
```

HTML

```
<form name="frm">

<select name="optdevices">
</select>

<input id="testID" type="button" value="TestAdd" />

</form>​
```

Comment: Thanks.  Fiddle will be really useful.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not valid as you have var in the function parameter. As long as you have syntax error in your script, the function won't be recognized. `function populatedropdown(var devicelist)` is not valid. There should not be `var` in the parameter

```
function populatedropdown(devicelist) {
    var devList = document.frm.optdevices;
    var arrDev = split(devicelist, ";");

     devList.options.length = 0; // this removes existing options

     for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
         var option = new Option(arrDev[i],i);
         devList.options[i] = option; 
     }
}
```